# EditeText On text changed is crashing

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have to convert some numeric editText in double and after text changed do a simple math operation. Everything works fine except On Text Changed: it crash whatever I do (also to change TextView with "hello world").

Here's my code:

```
hEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)
        {
            Double hDouble = Double.parseDouble(hEditText.toString());
            Double bDouble = Double.parseDouble(bEditText.toString());
            Double mDouble = Double.parseDouble(mEditText.getText().toString());
            Double miDouble = Double.parseDouble(miEditText.getText().toString());

            lResult.setText("" + Math.sqrt((hDouble * hDouble) + (bDouble * bDouble)));
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

**LOG**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.cosmo.fisicapp, PID: 21198
              java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
                  at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1071)
                  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
                  at com.example.cosmo.fisicapp.Equilibrio$1.afterTextChanged(Equilibrio.java:47)
                  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8525)
                  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:10788)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1222)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:583)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:509)
                  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:508)
                  at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
                  at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6533)
                  at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:6323)
                  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2742)
                  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9949)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
                  at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(ScrollView.java:391)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:439)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1861)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3141)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:535)
                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2530)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:353)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4742)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4713)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4249)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4302)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4268)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4395)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4276)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4452)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4249)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4302)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4268)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4276)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4249)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6676)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6650)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6611)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3917)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)

Comment: Add crash log ?

Comment: please post your logcat stack trace here.

Comment: I think you mean to say that onTextChanged() keeps crashing, correct? Because your afterTextChanged() is quite empty

Comment: I was meaning on text changed, typo

Comment: I've added log!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)
        {
          if(!charSequence.equals("")){
            Double hDouble = Double.parseDouble(charSequence.toString());
            Double bDouble = Double.parseDouble(charSequence.toString());
            Double mDouble = Double.parseDouble(charSequence.getText().toString());
            Double miDouble = Double.parseDouble(charSequence.getText().toString());

            lResult.setText("" + Math.sqrt((hDouble * hDouble) + (bDouble * bDouble)));
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code to :

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        Double hDouble = Double.parseDouble(hEditText.toString());
        Double bDouble = Double.parseDouble(bEditText.toString());
        Double mDouble = Double.parseDouble(mEditText.getText().toString());
        Double miDouble = Double.parseDouble(miEditText.getText().toString());

        lResult.setText("" + Math.sqrt((hDouble * hDouble) + (bDouble * bDouble)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing the following lines:
`Double hDouble = Double.parseDouble(hEditText.toString());` to
`Double hDouble = Double.parseDouble(hEditText.getText().trim());` and the other lines

Answer (score 0):

Your app would crash every time the parser doesn't produce a Double. Enclose every transformation from String to Double in a try/catch. If the user types anything other than numbers or ., or clears the EditText
 then the app will crash

Comment: The textfields is only number

Comment: Then check when `editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()` before you parse

Answer (score 0):

The method `afterTextChanged` can't crash because it is empty. The method `onTextChanged`, on the other hand, which makes extensive use of `Double.parseDouble(String)` most definitely can, as this will throw a `NumberFormatException` if you give it something that can't be converted to a double. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)).

To get around this, one possibility is to make a helper method so that you're not putting `try-catch` blocks everywhere and decide either to catch the exception and return a default value (such as `0D`) or let it propagate.

For example:

```
private double toDouble(String raw) {
    double val;
    try {
        val = Double.parseDouble(raw);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        val = 0D;
    }
    return val;
}
```

then your code in `onTextChanged` becomes

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)
    {
        Double hDouble = toDouble(hEditText.toString());
        Double bDouble = toDouble(bEditText.toString());
        Double mDouble = toDouble(mEditText.getText().toString());
        Double miDouble = toDouble(miEditText.getText().toString());

        lResult.setText("" + Math.sqrt((hDouble * hDouble) + (bDouble * bDouble)));
    }
```

Comment: Change `val = Double.parseDouble(val);` to `val = Double.parseDouble(raw);`

Comment: @Arfmann I've updated my answer. It wasn't working due to a typo which mTak pointed out.